# Does/has type theory influenced how to treat functions as values?

Tags: type-theory

Does/has type theory influenced how to treat functions as values?

Particularly, I still believe that it's general to think of functions with some input, e.g. $f(x)=x$ to be the value of the function, given the input. So the R.H.S., while being a function, is also a value. While the L.H.S. is a value.

However, from type theory perspective, one could perceive that $f(x) \space != \space x$, since they differ in types.

This is particularly confusing in programming languages such as Haskell, where e.g. `id:: a -> a` is not the same as `x::a`, even if `id` could map to the same value as `a`.

Then again, in Church encoding, there seems to be a separate "value container" meant to apply the function to its value.

Answer (score 2):

I do hope type theory starts influencing other folks in mathematics, because it generally handles this thing precisely in a way it's often not. For instance, your question seems to have a bit of confusion still in it.

For instance, you write $f(x) = x$, which as someone who's studied a lot of type theory, I generally take to mean a specification for what $f$ is. Note that I wrote $f$ on its own there, because that is how I'd refer to the function itself. $f(x)$ would be more like an expression with the function applied to a (free) variable. And when you go on to say $f(x) \neq x$, it doesn't make much sense in that context, because the specification of $f$ says that $f(x)$ probably reduces to $x$ (or at least is somehow equivalent to it).

What I would say is that $f \neq x$. Or, if you want to refer to the definiton of the function instead of the name, $(\lambda y. y) \neq x$. Note also that I changed the variable used, because the actual name used is irrelevant for *bound* variables.

However, it is definitely true that a lot of informal mathematics conflates a lot of these things in a confusing way, and mathematicians *in general* aren't as careful about all of this as type theorists and logicians tend to be (maybe even some type theorists aren't careful enough, especially if you read older presentations). I think [this article](http://math.andrej.com/2012/12/25/free-variables-are-not-implicitly-universally-quantified/) (and its comments) explain this and more a lot more thoroughly, if you're interested.